# HttpClient 415 Unsupported Media Type error

Tags: c#, .net

Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type Error when i try to get token from the identity server using HttpClient. But it works when I use RestClient. Why its not working with HttpClient.

Below is the code for using HttpClient

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
string clientId = "clientid";
string issuer = "https://ourrdomain/token";
string secretKey = "secret";

var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + secretKey);
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri(issuer),
    Headers = {
        { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray) },
        { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        { HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl.ToString(), "no-cache" },
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
    }
};
var response = _client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

Below is the code using RestClient

```
var request = new RestRequest();
var client = new RestClient(issuer);
string clientId = "clientid";
string issuer = "https://ourrdomain/token";
string secretKey = "secret";
var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientId + ":" + secretKey);
request.Method = Method.Post;
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
var response2 = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Side note: `response` needs `using`. And do NOT use `.Result` or you could get a deadlock, use `await` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**

The `415` Unsupported Media Type error in your `HttpClient` code is likely due to the way the content type and body are being set. In the `HttpClient` code, you're setting the `ContentType` header directly, but not providing the body content in the correct format

> **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.

The `HttpRequestMessage` should include an `HttpContent` object with the content type set correctly and the body encoded as form data.

Here's how you can fix the HttpClient code:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
string clientId = "clientid";
string issuer = "https://ourrdomain/token";
string secretKey = "secret";

var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{secretKey}");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true };

var requestData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
};
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

var response = _client.PostAsync(issuer, content).Result;
```

- The credentials are added to the default request headers, which is a
  cleaner way of adding headers that don't change often.
- The form data is being sent as `HttpContent` using
  `FormUrlEncodedContent`, which correctly sets the `Content-Type` header
  to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- We use `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient` which takes care of setting the
  proper `Content-Type` header and encoding the content.

Make sure to handle the Result properly, preferably by using async/await instead of .Result to avoid deadlocks and improve performance. Here's an example using `async/await`:

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> GetTokenAsync()
{
    // ... other code ...

    var response = await _client.PostAsync(issuer, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Deserialize the JSON response to a token response object
        var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(json);
        return tokenResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the error, log it, etc.
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this `async` method, we're handling the HTTP call asynchronously and returning the deserialized token response object. Always check if the response is successful before attempting to read the content.